# Registering Ansible Variables without the extra steps

Tags: ansible

Does anyone know if there is a way to target Ansible variable registery without adding a set_facts task?

For example, if I know my API call is going to return a chunk of garbage and I only need the tag "API.Response[0].session_id" from

```
API: {
   Response: [
         { session_id: "yolo" }
   ]
}
```

Currently, the only option I see is to register all of the output and then create ANOTHER task to set_fact to regex search it or the case of XML create TWO more tasks to xml parse it then set_fact to register the xml parsed output.

```
------- XML EXAMPLE ----------------
    <entry name="001606026760">
      <serial>001606026760</serial>
      <connected>yes</connected>
      <unsupported-version>no</unsupported-version>
      <hostname>us-583-int-fw-01</hostname>
      <ip-address>10.200.226.8</ip-address>
      <mac-addr></mac-addr>
      <uptime>72 days, 6:19:31</uptime>
      <family>200</family>
      <model>PA-200</model>
      <sw-version>8.0.0</sw-version>
      <app-version>8013-4681</app-version>
      <av-version>2599-3095</av-version>
      <wildfire-version>240995-243478</wildfire-version>
    </entry>


---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Get IP address from xmldata.
      xml:
        path: "data.xml"
        content: "text"
        xpath: "/entry/ip-address"
      register: test

    - set_fact:
        ip: "{{test['matches'][0]['ip-address']}}"
```

This seems like a waste of resources (storing unnecessary garbage) and time (adding tasks).

There has to be a way one could register specific object attributes to a variable directly from the response. That or at least let me specify my own regex to register.

**tl;dr: set_facts would not be necessary if there would be targeted response registry. Please tell me there is.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's a well-known annoyance of Ansible: there is no way to transform value at `register` level.

But you can use jinja magic here. Jinja variables aren't evaluated until the very last moment they used. That means you can define a variable equal to a variable which will be defined later.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Get IP address from xmldata.
      xml:
        path: "data.xml"
        content: "text"
        xpath: "/entry/ip-address"
      register: test_result

    - debug: var=ip
  vars:
      ip: "{{ test_result['matches'][0]['ip-address'] }}"
```